# Cannot deploy docker containers from different hosts

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration, ansible, containers

I'm integrating Docker into the Continous Integration of a project, so with each commit, it builds a docker image, pushes it to a private registry and runs that container on a machine running in OpenStack. We're using Ansible (v2.1) for the automation, so to interact with Docker, I'm using the **docker_container** module. Aside from just running the docker container, I need to inject some configuration files that vary depending on which environment I'm deploying to. I use the **volumes** option to inject the configuration files.

Everything seems to work ok, I can run the deployment several times, the docker containers get correctly replaced ... but the problem begins when the same process is run from a different host (like our Continous Integration host, Jenkins CI, or just another laptop). The docker image is built correctly, it gets pushed to the private registry, but when it tries to run the new container, it fails to remove the old one and halts. I'm getting the following ansible error:

```
fatal: [host-1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Error removing container xxxx: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error (\"Driver devicemapper failed to remove root filesystem xxx: remove /var/lib/docker/overlay/yyyy/merged: device or resource busy\")"}
```

I'm using the following docker_container task to run the container:

```
 - name: Run the application container
  docker_container:
    name: "myProject-{{ environment_env }}-app"
    image: "{{ docker_app_image }}"
    state: started
    pull: yes
    restart: yes
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    volumes:
    - "{{ remote_home }}/myProject_{{ environment_env }}/log:{{ log_dir }}"
    - "{{ remote_home }}/myProject_{{ environment_env }}/local_settings.py:/server/cms/local_settings.py:ro"
    - "{{ remote_home }}/myProject_{{ environment_env }}/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro"
    - "{{ remote_home }}/myProject_{{ environment_env }}/myProject.pem:/etc/certificates/myProject.pem:ro"
    - "{{ remote_home }}/myProject_{{ environment_env }}/myProject_private.pem:/etc/certificates/myProject_private.pem:ro"
    - "{{ remote_home }}/myProject_{{ environment_env }}/myProject_vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/myProject_vhost.conf:ro"
```

I've tried changing the docker driver from devicemapper to overlay, but the problem remains the same. Has anyone of you faced this problem before? Does it have to do with the file owner or permissions on the different host where the deployment is run and the docker system can't manage that? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Do the docker commands work (pull, stop, rm, run) if you run them from the CLI? Which version of docker are you running at the failing nodes?

Comment: @BMitch yeah, when I get the mentioned Ansible error of failed container removal, the manual CLI command `docker rm` also fails with the same error. I'm using the `Docker 1.12.1`, I have to destroy the machine and re-create it again in order to deploy again

Comment: Give lsof a try to see if you can track down what's locking access to the docker directories/files.

Comment: @BMitch I've checked that in fact it was `v1.12.0`, also checked the Docker GitHub repo and saw that their latest changelog for the `v1.12.2` includes "**Implement retry logic to prevent "Unable to remove filesystem" errors when using the aufs storage driver**", referencing this [PR](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/26536). I'll check if the problem persists in that version, and if possitive, will also check with the `lsof` command

Comment: @BMitch unfortunately the problem seems to persist with the `1.12.2` version :( the output of the lsof is a bit monstruous, 4K lines, and 650 lines with `grep docker`, I uploaded both to a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/lukasged/1641b6aae05645618a2eda7a29d342b9) , but I can't see there any line that would look like a docker mounted volume, only many lines referencing `/var/lib/docker/volumes/metadata.db`

Comment: I was looking at the directory in the error message, so something like: `sudo lsof +D /var/lib/docker/overlay/yyyy/merged` would filter the output. Not seeing anything listed in your gist makes me suspect that's also a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the answer myself, hopefully it will help somebody with the same problem I was having with Docker.

I followed [this guide](http://blog.hashbangbash.com/2014/11/docker-devicemapper-fix-for-device-or-resource-busy-ebusy/) , which basically consists on adding a parameter to the docker systemd unit file. I added the `MountFlags=private` line in the `[service]` section. It seems that the issue is related to the filesystem namespaces. With this fix, I can deploy the containers from as many hosts I want and there are 0 errors.

Comment: This issue was driving me nuts for a couple of days. But I did not face the bug since a day now after adding `MountFlags=private`. I just can't believe it!
Thanks that you are one of those guys who answers his own question :-)